# NodeJS "Request path contains unescaped characters" Doesn't work when using proxy

Tags: node.js, npm, proxy, request

NPM Version  - 3.5.2
Node Version - v8.10.0
Request-Promise - "request-promise": "^4.2.2"

I'm having an issue on my Ubuntu 18.04 server running NodeJS and NPM when using a proxy. I am getting the error `Request path contains unescaped characters`

When I do not use a proxy the request works fine. It's definitely not an encoding issue.

- I have tried using multiple proxies from different providers that do not work.
- I have deployed a new server to see if it was another issue.
- I have tried different URLs

  ```
  async makeRequest(opts = {}) {

  let id = Math.random().toString(36).substring(7);

  var msg = `[${id}] Request to ${opts.url}`
      msg += (opts.proxy !== undefined) ? ` | ${opts.proxy}` : ``;

  this.ts(msg)

  var resp = this.request(opts).then((res) => {
      var msg = `[${id}] Status: ${res.statusCode}`;
          msg += (res.headers.location !== undefined) ? ` | Location: ${res.headers.location}` : ``;

      this.ts(msg);

      res.id = id;
      return res;
  }).catch((err) => {
      // console.log(err);
      this.ts(`[${id}] ${err.name} - ${err.message}`)
      return false;
  })

  return resp
  }
  ```

The opts look like

`{
url: "https://google.com",
proxy: "http://user:pass@proxyserver:port"
}`

Comment: Perhaps your proxy doesn't support `https`, What happens if you change the value of the `url` property to `http` instead ?

Comment: @RobC It is the same issue. It actually turned out to be me not having the default "Request" library installed for some weird reason